# Why was the Regalia Type-D reverted in chapter 7?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

At some early point in the game (think chapter 3) I upgraded the Regalia to Type-D. All good.

However, in the end of chapter 6 there was a message saying the Regalia has been reverted back to its original form, and indeed, the Type-D is gone, and I can't go off-road anymore.

Why did it happen? Is there some official/logical explanation for this?

Note: as part of the main quest, I can't go back to Hammerhead in order to try changing it back.

Comment: Were you able to go back to Cindy and change it back to Regalia Type D?

Comment: @Wondercricket not yet, I'm now "stuck" between two blockades and can't go back to the pre-chapter 7 places. I assume that in the next chapter the Type-D will be back, either automatically or by changing manually again, but wonder why I can't use it in 7.

Comment: Are you looking for something that makes sense in terms of story, or in terms of gameplay (or both)? A common example of the latter is "we needed to keep the player within X area".

Comment: @ChrisHayes both, thanks. (though the later might be considered opinion based)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later half of the story is significantly more railroaded (both literally and figuratively) than the first, which is basically a true open-world game. After you embark on the boat, the Regalia can't even be used again (only returns in a single driving scene / minigame, if I remember correctly) until you get to the post-game content, where the modification becomes available again.